# prefill or pass query parameters to child resource

Tags: admin-on-rest

How I can get access to query parameters in child resource create form?

For example if I want to have a button on parent resource edit page which redirects to
`/childresource/create?parentid=123` and then on child resource create form we have `<SelectInput source="parentid" />` and I want this to be preselected?

Is it somehow possible already? Would it be better with custom react routing for example to `/parent/123/addchild` and have whole custom create component or maybe just customer selectinput component?

I already have functional create page for child but it would be really nice to somehow prefill values.

Comment: You can create your own custom input components and wrap withRouter hoc

Comment: Thanks for the tip I was able to proceed a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your second question:

```
ProductSelect.defaultProps = {
  location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

// This is the component exported and known by admin-on-rest, not ProductSelect
const EnhancedProductSelect = withRouter(ProductSelect);

// Hence, this is the one which needs a defaultProp for addField
EnhancedProductSelect.defaultProps = {
  addField: true
};

export default EnhancedProductSelect;
```

Does this help for the first question ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/pp0o4x40p0

The relevant code parts are:

- the `CreateCommentButton` component inside `src/posts.js`
- the `CommentCreate` component inside `src/comments.js` (note how we set the `defaultValue` prop on `SimpleForm`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I still have same issue when using component from admin on rest. It seems to have something to do with that withRouter wrapping. I updated code if it helps anything.

Comment: Hi Gildas I  set this up -> https://codesandbox.io/s/zqvp0r7y3l .If you try this url you will see the problem https://zqvp0r7y3l.codesandbox.io/#/products/create?ProductId=125

Comment: Added an example in my answer

Comment: Haven't tested it with admin-on-rest 1.4 though. I used the `2.0.0` beta